# Wrong date output from database at 3 o'clock

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I am using postgresql database. The date is entered correctly at +03, but is displayed when requesting a postman or a browser 3 hours less. What to do in such a situation. Checked the settings, everything is fine. Screenshots and code below. Help, thanks!

Date in database: `2023-01-01 00:00:00.000000`
Output: `2022-12-31 21:00:00.000`

```
 @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
        System.out.println("Date in UTC: " + new Date().toString());
    }
```

[image]

The data type of the PostgreSQL column is `timestamp`.

Comment: the difference in hours is: 3. Do you see that line in your properties: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=+03 ? What do you think that does?

Comment: @Stultuske thank you for answer! In fact, it adds the time I entered by 3 hours and saves it in the database. But if I remove +03 then the database will save time 3 less than my current time

Comment: no, it won't. meaning somewhere you are using a different timezone which differs three hours from the one you want to be using

Comment: What is the output of your code snippet?

Comment: Do you understand that `java.util.Date#toString`tells a lie? That method applies your JVM’s current default time zone, while the object’s value is in UTC (an offset of zero).

Comment: You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: @BasilBourque What should be done now to solve this problem?

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: @Yevgeniy What problem? You have not defined a problem. All you’ve done is mention a database, and shown two lines of code *without* any database-related code. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And I’m guessing your issue has already been addressed in existing Questions and Answers. But you’ve not bothered to search for those, otherwise you would have learned to avoid the obsolete legacy date-time classes.